# Text doesn't appear over CameraPreview layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a camera screen in my app that resembles a scanner apps screen. The final design should look something like this:

[image]

I was able to create the camera+layout screen by using `CameraPreview` widget and providing a layout child:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    body: GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () async {
          // some logic
        },
        child: Column(children: [
          Stack(children: [
            Text("Center your camera over the indicator ", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0),
              child: FutureBuilder<void>(
                future: _initializeControllerFuture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
                    return CameraPreview(_controller,
                        child: MaterialPreviewOverlay(
                          overlayColor: overlayColor,
                        ));
                  } else {
                    // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                },
              ),
            )
          ])
        ])),
  );
}
```

The `MaterialPreviewOverlay` doesn't have too much logic, mainly it calls the painter that looks like this:

```
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  final screenRect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
  final cutOutWidth = screenRect.width - 80;
  final cutOutHeight = cutOutWidth * 1.7;
  final cutOut = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
      Rect.fromCenter(
          center: screenRect.center,
          width: cutOutWidth,
          height: cutOutHeight),
      bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(40),
      topRight: const Radius.circular(40),
      topLeft: const Radius.circular(40)
  );
  final cutOutPath = Path.combine(PathOperation.difference,
      Path()..addRect(screenRect), Path()..addRRect(cutOut));
  final borderPaint = Paint()
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = 5 // strokeWidth is painted 50/50 outwards and inwards.
    ..color = overlayColor;//.withAlpha(160);
  canvas
    ..drawPath(cutOutPath, backgroundPaint)
    ..drawRRect(cutOut.deflate(borderPaint.strokeWidth / 2), borderPaint);
}
```

For some reason the `Text` widget isn't shown at all. I tried with `Stack` (like in the provided code example) and without. If I put the text below the `FutureBuilder` widget the text is shown (both with and without using `Stack`) and if I add an `appBar` to the `Scaffold` the text is also shown beneath the app bar. But I do not need the app bar, why wouldn't the text appear in my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to align the `Stack` widget using `(alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter)` with no success, I saw it does work if I put, for example, `AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter`.

Then I realized that text does appear in `topCenter` but is hidden by the iPhone notch. Padding it, solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Text` widget doesn't show up since your `Stack` order is `Text` and then the `CameraPreview`. This means that your `Text` widget will be drawn and on top of it your `CameraPreview` will be drawn, which means that your `Text` widget isn't visible anymore. To fix your issue you have to reorder your `Stack` so that `CameraPreview` is before `Text`.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    CameraPreview(),
    Text('My Text'),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Didn't mention I tried it - doesn't work either